# Team Foundation Server 2010: structure build definitions in folders

Tags: build-definition

We have a lot of build definitions on our TFS 2010 for the same 'Team Project'.
But not all build tasks are relevant for developers or they haven't the privileges to queue a new build.

Is there a way to manage the definitions with folders / tags or something else to keep it simple? Otherwise the developers will lose the overview if tens of build definitions are available.

thank you and kind regards,
danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a [VS 2010 plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35daa606-4917-43c4-98ab-38632d9dbd45) that kind of does this. We've just tried it and it really helps manage the build definitions but it requires you to have a naming convention in place

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible. You can vote on https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/582949/tfs2010-team-explorer-multiple-build-folders-for-team-project to have it in the next version of Visual Studio (aka Dev11).
The more votes, the more likely it gets higher on the backlog.